# Extract text from certain tag and allow id, class etc

Tags: javascript

How can i extract text from certain tag and allow id, class's , attribute's to remain in the tag?

I tried to do this:

```
var htmlRegexG = /<body>(.*?)<\/body>/g;
var str ='<body>Probably.Today</body>'.match(htmlRegexG);
```

This works if body do not have id class's or attribute's.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the getElementsByTagName method to get the data from inside a tag. Below is an example on how to return all the content from the body tag.

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent
console.log(test)
```

If you are dealing with a page where you want the text from a tag that repeats a few times on the page you will either need to specify the index or loop through all the indexes:

```
<body>
  <p>
    hello world
  </p>
  <p>
    goodbye world
  </p>
 </body>
```

script:

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  console.log(test[i].textContent)
 }
```